# (Proof-Verication) Show these two matrices are similar

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I thought of this problem, and I want to know if this proof is correct, or even if it is a vaild question.

> **Question** Show that these two $n\times n$ matrices are similar.
> $A$=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & & &  & \\
> 1 & 1 & &  & \\
>  & 1 & ...& & \\
>  &  &  &1 & \\
> & &  & 1 &1
> \end{bmatrix}
> $B$=\begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & & &  &_nC_n\times(-1)^{n-1} \\
> 1 & 0 & &  &.. \\
>  & 1 & ...& &.. \\
>  &  &  &0 &_nC_2\times(-1)^{2-1} \\
> & &  & 1 & _nC_1\times(-1)^{1-1}
> \end{bmatrix}
> where $A$ has $1$s in the main diagonal, and the diagonal right below, and B has $0$ in the main diagonal, and $1$s in the diagonal right below except the last column.

I thought of this problem when I was learning Jordan canonical forms(JCF) and rational canonical forms(RCF). I proved in this way.

> **Proof** Think of a $n\times n$ matrix, $P$ such that its minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial is both $(x-1)^n$, and a linear map $T$ such that $[T]=P$. Then $A$ is the JCF of this matrix, and B would be the RCF of this matrix, as it is the companion matrix of $P$, using bionomial expansion. Therefore, there exists two bases $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$ such that $[T]_{\beta_1}$ is $A$, and $[T]_{\beta_2}$ is $B$. Since $A$ is similar to $P$ and $B$ is similar to $P$, thus they are similar to each other.

Is this a right proof?